# Call multilookuplist by title and verify content in SharePoint Site

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, multi-select

I have this multilookuplist where user double click to movevalues to the right side. I need to make a method to check if the multilookuplist is empty. 
I need to call it by the name as it is a sharepoint site.
The code looks like the following:

```
<span dir="none">
    <input id="ctl00_MultiLookupPicker" 
    name="ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$MultiLookupPicker" 
    type="hidden"></input>
    <input id="ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_MultiLookupPicker_data" 
    name="$ctl00$MultiLookupPicker$data" 
    type="hidden" 
    value="272|tAS (blaba)|t |t |t235|tAP (blalbla)|t |t |t224|tAR (blalbla)|t |t "></input>
    <input id="ctl00_MultiLookupPicker_initial"
    name="ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$MultiLookupPicker$initial" 
    type="hidden" value=""></input>
    <table class="ms-long" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td class="ms-input">
                <select name="ctl00$m$g_ctl00$SelectCandidate" 
                id="ctl00_ctl00_SelectCandidate" 
                multiple="multiple" title="Employees possible values" 
                onchange="GipSelectCandidateItems(ctl00_ctl00_MultiLookupPicker_m);" 
                ondblclick="GipAddSelectedItems(ctl00_ctl00_MultiLookupPicker_m); return false" 
                style="width:143px;height:125px;overflow:scroll;">
            </select>
            </td>
            <td style="padding-left:10px">
            <td align="center" valign="middle" class="ms-input"><button 
            id="ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_AddButton" 
            class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" 
            onclick="GipAddSelectedItems(ctl00_ctl00_MultiLookupPicker_m); return false"> Add &gt; </button><br />
                <br /><button id="cctl04_ctl00_ctl00_RemoveButton"
                class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" 
                onclick="GipRemoveSelectedItems(ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_MultiLookupPicker_m); return false"> &lt; Remove </button>
            </td>
            <td style="padding-left:10px">
            <td class="ms-input">
                <select name="ctl04$ctl00$ctl00$SelectResult" 
                id="ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_SelectResult" 
                multiple="multiple" 
                title="Employees selected values" 
                onchange="GipSelectResultItems(ctl00_MultiLookupPicker_m);" 
                ondblclick="GipRemoveSelectedItems(_ctl00_ctl00_MultiLookupPicker_m); return false" 
                style="width:143px;height:125px;overflow:scroll;">
            </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</span>
```

The following is the method that I try to make it validate that some lines are selected and moved from "Employees possible values" to "Employees selected values"

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Script/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="/sites/Competence_Man/Style%20Library/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="/sites/Competence_Man/Style%20Library/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"> 
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){
alert("Hello from Me");
//ValidateFields();

});

function ValidateFields()
 {
if (("[title='Employees selected values'].val()==null) 
{
 // checked, so do something
 alert("Test 2")
 }


 }

 _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("ValidateFields()");


  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below for your reference.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){   
    ValidateFields();
});
function ValidateFields(){
    if ($("select[title='Employees selected values'] option").length==0){
        // checked, so do something
        alert("Test 2");
    }
}
</script>
```

If you want to do the validation when save item form, we need override the **PreSaveAction()** method.

References: [SharePoint 2010 Validation using Javascript](https://workflowssimplified.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/sharepoint-2010-validation-using-javascript/)